# Is there a blanket way to change references to styles/scripts in node_modules when migrating to Yarn PNP?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, package.json, yarn-v3

I am attempting to migrate an existing project using Yarn with the node_modules linker to pnp, however in this project there are several references to things like stylesheets or scripts that would normally be stored in node_modules. Is there an easy/quick way to change existing references, or is it necessary to unplug every necessary package and manually change the path reference to the new location?